# how to apply more then one custom CSS property in extent report?

Tags: java, css, json, selenium-webdriver, extentreports

how to apply more then one custom css property in extent report ?
i used  json file >>

```
{
  "theme": "DARK",

  "encoding": "utf-8",

  "protocol": "HTTPS",

  "timelineEnabled": false,

  "offlineMode": true,

  "thumbnailForBase64": false,

  "documentTitle": "Extend_Report_View",

  "reportName": "Report Views",

  "timeStampFormat": "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a",

  
  "css":".side-nav-menu { border-right: 1px solid #cefffb !important} ,.badge-primary {background-color: #8bbfcb}"

}
```

after that I loaded this json :>>   `sparkReporter.loadJSONConfig(new File("./src/test/resources/config_ExtentReport.json"));`

in this case just the first property `(.side-nav-menu { border-right: 1px solid #cefffb !important})` is worked !!

I need to apply many CSS property in extent report

Comment: The given css is not valid. Try to remove the comma (`,`) in front of the selector `.badge-primary`.